# Using the navigation.navigate inside a createMaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I started out a bit with react-native, and I'm trying to make a "hello word" app to see how it works.
I made a menu with "tab" at the top of my screen

In the app.js I'm adding the createStackNavigator to set my routes
**App.js**

```
import { ... }
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({     
    Main: { screen: Main},
    CScreen: {screen: FormCScreen},
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
render() {
    return (
        <AppNavigator />    
    );
  }
}
```

This is my **main** screen, where I set the tabs.

**Main.js**

```
imports {AScreen, BScreen} ...
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
{
   A: AScreen,
   B: BScreen,
},
{
  tabBarPosition: 'top',

});

export default class Main extends Component {

render() {
    return (  
      <Tab/>
    );
  }
}
```

**BScreen.js**

Now on one of my BScreen tabs, I want to click on a button, where I hope it loads the screen (CScreen)

```
imports ...
export default class BScreenextends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
               <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CScreen')}>
                <Text>Click here to open CScreen</Text>
                   </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

It can render all components correctly, the only problem is that when I click the button to display the CScreen, nothing happens.
It is as if loading the Tab I lost the instacia of my navigator.

```
Main
 Tab 
 A
 B Button (Open CScreen) ~> this is not working
```

How can I open the screen through a button inside a tab?

[EDIT]
Console.log ScreenB

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV1BY.jpg

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html
Can you console.log this.props.navigation from BScreen?
I think you need to poptotop

Comment: Hi, update my question with a print of the log, if necessary I can send another one. why use popToTop? will it lose it's navigate when I use the tab?

Comment: I added this.props.navigation.dispatch (StackActions.popToTop ()); for my componentWillMount and nothing has changed, I continue the same way without being able to use the navigation.navigate

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3254

Comment: I believe you can try this, even though you aren't using a drawer stack, the logic should be the same

Comment: The idea is to reset my navigate right? where is the right way to reset? in ScreeB or in Main.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your trying to achieve StacksOverTabs mode of navigation setup,

The mistake you made is `Main` screen being a normal Component inside which you have rendered the Tab Component i.e createMaterialTopTabNavigator. Hence the Tab Component will not get the correct navigation prop from the StackNavigator

Instead, you have to make `Main` screen itself a createMaterialTopTabNavigator.

For example,

```
 const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({     
     Main: { screen: MainTab}, // MainTab is itself a TabNavigator now
     CScreen: {screen: FormCScreen},
 });

 const MainTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
   {
      A: AScreen,
      B: BScreen,
   },
   {
     tabBarPosition: 'top',

   });
 );
```

Check out the official examples code in GitHub, inside that navigate to StacksOverTabs

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I just implemented this way and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could also have put this at the top of your App class I believe:

```
static router = AppNavigator.router;
```

There is more information here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html#explicitly-rendering-more-than-one-navigator

Comment: Yes, along with explicitly sending the navigation props to the child navigator: `<AppNavigator  navigation={ this.props.navigation } />`. I like this solution better because e.g. it allows for a custom header, etc.